# Should I use ALLOCA_N if I'm going to release the memory myself?

Tags: ruby, ruby-c-extension

From [the pickaxe](http://media.pragprog.com/titles/ruby3/ext_ruby.pdf):

> You may sometimes need to allocate memory in an extension tha t won’t
>   be used for object storage—perhaps you have a giant bitmap for a Bloom
>   filter, an image, or a whole bunch of little structures that Ruby
>   doesn’t use directly. To work correctly with the garbage collector,
>   you should use the following memory allocation routines. These
>   routines do a little bit more work than the st andard malloc function.
>   For instance, if ALLOC_N determines that it cannot allocate the
>   desired amount of mem ory, it will invoke the garbage collector to try
>   to reclaim some space. It will raise a NoMemError if it can’t or if
>   the requested amount of memory is invalid

But in a given function, I know exactly when release the memory. In this case, should I still using `ALLOC_N` to alloc the memory?

Is there legitime cases when I should free the memory myself, or it is better always use `ALLOC_N` and don't care about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably should use `ALLOC_N` to manage memory allocation dynamically, where your C code needs to store things in independently of object data, and the stored data needs to persist over more than one method call (therefore you cannot be certain that deallocation within specific C functions would be called).

If you are just creating something then throwing it away, all within the context of one complex method call, then you can use plain C approaches for memory management. The C stack is fine for the real basics E.g. just declare `int foo[1000];` and you can use that array internally, C will use the stack and clean up as normal - Ruby of course has no access to this data, unless you copy it into something at the end. Don't over-use this though, `int foo[1000000];` risks blowing the stack and causing a segfault.

The documentation implies one other reason to use `ALLOC_N` - you will avoid *some* out-of-memory situations due to the call to garbage collection. Also, you will get a slightly friendlier Ruby-managed process failure if you really are out of memory (as opposed to whatever your C routine would do).

Answer (score 3):

`ALLOC_N` doesn't free the memory you allocated. If it fails on the first attempt to allocate you memory it will trigger the GC in an attempt to free up more memory and then try again.

You should still free the memory allocated by `ALLOC_N`. But use `xfree` instead of `free` - this isn't that well described unfortunately in guides such as http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/ext_ruby.html but you find it used in the Ruby source and the source of other Ruby C Extensions.

Comment: Nice blog that explain C Extensions: http://blog.aeolusproject.org/category/ruby/page/2/

Comment: Newer function might be to use `ruby_xfree`.